# Grid View to show diferent Container

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

**How to fix when user don't have posted 3rt image in grid I have error, but when user have posted one or two image grid work fine**

Basically I wanted to use 2 Container() with difrent design, when in post have 3 image to show Container() from code down, but when have 2 image to show Container() designed to show for 2 image..

**Error image**

↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓

[Image of grid error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxPQv.jpg)

```
     child: Card(
                            // child: Container(
                            child: imageList[position].imagesPath.length ==
                                    1
                                ? CachedNetworkImage(
                                    imageUrl:
                                        imageList[position].imagesPath[0],
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                  )
                                : Center(
                                    child: Container(
                                      color: Colors.transparent,
                                      child: Stack(
                                        children: [
                                          Row(
                                            children: [
                                              SizedBox(
                                                width: 5,
                                              ),
                                              Column(
                                                children: [
                                                  SizedBox(
                                                    height: 7,
                                                  ),
                                                  Container(
                                                    child:
                                                        CachedNetworkImage(
                                                      imageUrl: imageList[
                                                              position]
                                                          .imagesPath[0],
                                                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                    ),
                                                    height: 50,
                                                    width: 45,
                                                    // color: Colors.red,
                                                  ),
                                                  SizedBox(
                                                    height: 2,
                                                  ),
                                                  // imageList[position]
                                                  //                 .imagesPath[
                                                  //             2] ==
                                                  //         null
                                                  //     ? null
                                                  //     :
                                                  Container(
                                                    child:
                                                        CachedNetworkImage(
                                                      imageUrl: imageList[
                                                              position]
                                                          .imagesPath[2],
                                                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                    ),
                                                    height: 50,
                                                    width: 45,
                                                  ),
                                                  SizedBox(
                                                    height: 7,
                                                  ),
                                                ],
                                              )
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                          Positioned(
                                            right: 5,
                                            top: 3.5,
                                            child: Container(
                                              child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                                imageUrl:
                                                    imageList[position]
                                                        .imagesPath[1],
                                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                              ),
                                              height: 110,
                                              width: 60,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),

                            // old grid view
                            // GridView.builder(
                            // itemCount: imageList[position]
                            //     .imagesPath
                            //     .length,
                            // itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
                            //   child: CachedNetworkImage(
                            //     imageUrl: imageList[position]
                            //         .imagesPath[index],
                            //     fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            //   ),
                            // ),
                            //     gridDelegate:
                            //         SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                            //       crossAxisCount: 2,
                            //       childAspectRatio: 1,
                            //       mainAxisSpacing: .1,
                            //       crossAxisSpacing: .1,
                            //     ),
                            //   ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      gridDelegate:
                          SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: 3,
                        childAspectRatio: 1.1 / 1.1,
                        mainAxisSpacing: .1,
                        crossAxisSpacing: .1,
                      ),
                    ),
```

Comment: so you need to show the no.of grids based on the no.of images coming and then need to display them accordingly ? @ComaXD EA1

Comment: I will try do explain now, user in my app are able to post: one, two or tree image from once, if user post one image code work properly, and I wanted to make design in greed when user post  2 or 3 image,  so I made two difrent container wich will display 3 or 2 image, but im not able to use both Container() in grid, because now in code is " if post is not 1 image Then post is 3 image, and if in greed in this moment have 2 image this show error, so we need to make also if post is not 1 image or 3 image, then post is 2 image... if you understand..

Comment: You can make it dynamic to support images based on length .. .?? Like using you Grid View the one you commented out !!

Comment: Right now is like this, but when I made like this then error go but still not able to show difrent container..